# I'm deleting my profile

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-users

I don't expect to be missed (or for this post to survive).

For the record, I'm leaving over SE management's removal of a moderator.  A moderator I never knew and never interacted with.  But whose reputation appears to have been smeared by an SE manager, from Meta through the chatrooms and all the way into [the newspapers](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/).

To the managers responsible for this debacle: you need to resign, or be dismissed.  When someone's gone, I'll sign up again.

John

Comment: Upvoting for support, sorry to see you or any other user go. Good luck!

Comment: Rather than having your account deleted and anonymized, why not place the reason for your leaving in your profile, and make a slight change to your user name. That wil leave a more lasting and visible explanation if things continue going downhill. But if SE finds their way out of the hole they have dug for themselves, you can return with the privileges you've already earned.

Comment: As above comment suggests, please reconsider deletion. You may write your thoughts in profile and mention that you are no more active. Additionally, you may change the display name to indicate that you are not active. Just in case, the things become right in future and you want to come back.... Anyway; best of luck...

Comment: @AmitJoshi Thank you for the thoughts.  I've seen too many knowing bad actors in positions of power in my career.  I feel the need to make my intent unmistakably clear, and burn to the ground everything I can set a match to.  If the SO of 5-10 years ago should ever re-emerge, I'd consider it the greatest of pleasures to try to earn back my privileges.  Hope springs eternal.

Comment: "burn to the ground everything I can set a match to." In that case, will you be editing all of your questions/answers before you leave?

Comment: @user10762409: (self) post vandalism is not permitted here.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I don’t think our paths have ever crossed on the site, but as with all users who are departing, I’m sorry to see you go.

For every user who leaves, it measurably decreases the usefulness of the site overall, especially for those who have contributed many answers.

It’s incredibly sad for something that could have been avoided entirely, or certainly easily walked back by a half-competent manager—or even just one with a little humility and introspection.

Maybe some day the remaining community who manages to stick it out will have managed to get control of this place again. Or maybe not. Either way, best of luck to you in all your future pursuits. Enjoy all the free time!

Comment: `it measurably decreases the usefulness of the site overall` That's the goal! If they don't want to treat people correctly, they _will_ and _have been_ losing key users and moderators.